# How to stop killing the queue command in laravel?

Tags: laravel, queue

I want this command `php artisan queue:work` stays active and not get killed for a long time...
when we have queues, and we run the server, if we only use the command php artisan queue:work, it can get killed for some reason and our queues don't work anymore. what should I do in this case?

Comment: use something like supervisor as the docs suggest

Comment: Thanks, It is for Linux operating system, can I use for other OS as well? What if I don't use Linux here?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite ambiguous , but I'll assume that you need the command to run whilst accessing that same instance of command line without `closing` or `stopping` the process.

I would recommend using `Screens` for this which allow you to effectively have virtual terminals open within the one you have.

Give the following article a read

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server

Comment: Can you check storage/logs/laravel-log. See if there are any errors, otherwise please check to see if there have been any memory issues